# Finding records in second table not in first

Tags: sql-server

This is an interesting twist for me on the old "find unmatched records in another table" problem commonly solved with a left join/null check. I have not found an answer to my need in the forums in my searches.

I have a table A and a table B that each have the same fields A and B. A is a string, B is an integer.

```
+-------------------+   +-------------------+
|      Table A      |   |      Table B      |
| Field A | Field B |   | Field A | Field B |
+---------+---------+   +---------+---------+
|    A    |    1    |   |    B    |    1    |
|    A    |    2    |   |    B    |    2    |
+---------+---------+   |    B    |    3    |
                        |    B    |    4    |
                        +---------+---------+
```

So the query I run needs to generate a result list like the following:

```
+-------------------+
|      Table A      |
| Field A | Field B |
+---------+---------+
|    A    |    3    |
|    A    |    4    |
+---------+---------+
```

I can clearly segregate the values (2,3,4) using a left/right join to table A from B; however, I am struggling with how to get field A from Table A when I have records in Table B that have no match in table A using a pure set operation. For example, the following code gets me all of FieldB, but FieldA is null.

```
SELECT
    TableA.FieldA
    ,TableB.FieldB
FROM
    TableA
    RIGHT JOIN TableB ON TableA.FieldB = TableB.FieldB
```

Importantly, I have to perform this using a set operation, so no WHILE constructs, intermediate/temp tables via inserts, etc.

I appreciate any guidance/suggestions.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

Thanks for the quick posts. Several folks mentioned using <> on the inner join. I did that originally on several tests and got the Cartesian product of the tables, which turns out to be a large number of records. I moved away from that solution for about 2 hours. These posts rekindled that fire.

So I took another stab at it and added a GROUP BY clause to the query. However, for some reason, I was still seeing records where there was similarity. So, I had to then strip out records where the two tables had common records. The final SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT
    FieldA
    ,FieldB
FROM
    TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.FieldB <> TableB.FieldB
WHERE
    FieldB NOT IN (SELECT TableB.FieldB FROM TableB INNER JOIN TableA ON TableA.FieldB = TableB.FieldB)
GROUP BY
    FieldA
    ,FieldB
```

This seems to work okay...

UPDATE #2:

Here's another update with the actual table structures as my original post appears to be unclear. Please note that I can recreate the exact occurrence of the issue I described and the solution solution using this code:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblControlData
(
    fldCN int
);

CREATE TABLE #tblCompData
(
    fldCompanyID int
    ,fldCN int
);

INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(4);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(5);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(6);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(7);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(8);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(9);

INSERT INTO #tblCompData (fldCompanyID,fldCN) VALUES(34,1);
INSERT INTO #tblCompData (fldCompanyID,fldCN) VALUES(34,2);
INSERT INTO #tblCompData (fldCompanyID,fldCN) VALUES(34,3);

SELECT
    #tblCompData.fldCompanyID
    ,#tblControlData.fldCN
FROM
    #tblCompData
    CROSS JOIN #tblControlData
WHERE
    #tblControlData.fldCN NOT IN (SELECT fldCN FROM #tblCompData)
GROUP BY
    #tblCompData.fldCompanyID
    ,#tblControlData.fldCN

DROP TABLE #tblControlData
DROP TABLE #tblCompData
```

If you run just a cross join on this table, you get the Cartesian product, which is not right. So then add the GROUP BY and it is still not right. Then subtract out the common items with the NOT IN and it is correct.

The results are as follows:

```
fldCompanyID    fldCN
34                4
34                5
34                6
34                7
34                8
34                9
```

I've been on this for a while and my mind is fried, but if you all see a better way, I'm open to suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Just add not equal when you are comparing field B of both tables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion--see solution above.

Comment: Please make sure that you include all the scenarios in your question and your actual expected result from the next questions. @Mike P.

Comment: See actual code above...

Comment: Note that while this works on small data sets, the cross join is a performance dog on any data set of appreciable size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT
    FieldA
    ,FieldB
FROM
    TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.FieldB <> TableB.FieldB
WHERE
    FieldB NOT IN (SELECT TableB.FieldB FROM TableB INNER JOIN TableA ON TableA.FieldB = TableB.FieldB)
GROUP BY
    FieldA
    ,FieldB
```

This is a little more compact...

```
SELECT
    #tblCompData.fldCompanyID
    ,#tblControlData.fldCN
FROM
    #tblCompData
    CROSS JOIN #tblControlData
WHERE
    #tblControlData.fldCN NOT IN (SELECT fldCN FROM #tblCompData)
GROUP BY
    #tblCompData.fldCompanyID
    ,#tblControlData.fldCN
```

Amazing what clarity a bit of sleep provides...

The following answer runs faster...

```
CREATE TABLE #tblControlData
(
    fldCN int
);

CREATE TABLE #tblCompData
(
    fldCompanyID int
    ,fldCN int
);

INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(1);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(2);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(3);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(4);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(5);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(6);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(7);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(8);
INSERT INTO #tblControlData (fldCN) VALUES(9);

INSERT INTO #tblCompData (fldCompanyID,fldCN) VALUES(34,1);
INSERT INTO #tblCompData (fldCompanyID,fldCN) VALUES(34,2);
INSERT INTO #tblCompData (fldCompanyID,fldCN) VALUES(34,9);

SELECT
    #tblInterim.fldCompanyID
    ,#tblInterim.fldControlCN
FROM
(
    SELECT
        #tblCompData.fldCompanyID
        ,#tblTemp.fldCN AS fldControlCN
    FROM
        #tblCompData
        CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT
            fldCN
        FROM
            #tblControlData
    ) AS #tblTemp
    GROUP BY
        #tblCompData.fldCompanyID
        ,#tblTemp.fldCN
) AS #tblInterim
WHERE
    #tblInterim.fldControlCN NOT IN (SELECT fldCN FROM #tblCompData WHERE     #tblInterim.fldCompanyID = #tblCompData.fldCompanyID)
GROUP BY
    #tblInterim.fldCompanyID
    ,#tblInterim.fldControlCN

DROP TABLE #tblControlData
DROP TABLE #tblCompData
```

Comment: Why does you require a NOT IN again? Seems the query looks like a complex one and time consuming. @Mike P.

Comment: I was wondering the same thing Sarath. I wish I knew. The query returns the correct data set when the "NOT IN" is there, but not when the "NOT IN" is missing. That seemed odd to me several hours ago which is why I moved away from the <> on the inner join in the first place.

Comment: I think requirement is not clear or you are not able to explain real data scenario.It appear that SOMEHOW you hv just manage to get  the desire output.Which may backfire with real sample data.

Comment: Yes. You are right KumarHarsh. The OP's requirement was not clear. He doesn't mention the scenarios. @KumarHarsh

Comment: KumarHarsh, what was missing from the original post was the possibility for a second record in Table A. Thus, all solutions presented appeared to work; however, all solutions presented do not account for more than 1 record in Table A. I now understand why you need the NOT IN in the query--because I have to filter out all records in the Cartesian product where there is commonality because a Cartesian product returns ALL rows. The GROUP BY reduces the duplicates in the Cartesian product result set.

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
SELECT * INTO A
FROM
(
SELECT 'A' [Field A] ,1 [Field B]
)TAB    


SELECT * INTO B
FROM
(
SELECT 'B' [Field A] ,1 [Field B]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' [Field A] ,2 [Field B]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' [Field A] ,3 [Field B]
UNION ALL
SELECT 'B' [Field A] ,4 [Field B]
)TAB
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT A.[Field A],B.[Field B]
FROM A 
CROSS JOIN B  
WHERE A.[Field B]<>B.[Field B]
```

- **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38e53/2)**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion--see solution above.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but this solution does not work with more than one record in table A. Add a second record in your fiddle to Table A. It breaks (I believe that fact is where my original post was perhaps a bit unclear).